# Run MAC OSX application from another MAC OSX application

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is any default method to run MAC OSX application from another MAC OSX application instead of fork + exec. Language c/objective c ?

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: What do you mean by "default method"?  What is wrong with fork+exec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of options.

- [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html) for C.
- `NSWorkspace` & `NSTask` in Cocoa.
- The `open` command-line utility.

Comment: You could tell which one is the best (on your opinion) and elaborate on that one giving an example on how to use it.